# iOS - Open email in Calendar or Reminder

Tags: ios, email

Is it possible to create an extension to mail.app to open an email in say Calendar and/or Reminders

For example, create an "open in" function that opens a new calendar event and populates the notes section of the calendar event with the body text from the email?

If an extension is not possible, would it be possible to write an email client that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Its not possible to create an extension to mail.app.
By writing email client, you can fetch the body of email with in your app and ca pass this info calendar or reminder.